# two keys with the same name "$or"

Tags: python, json, parse-platform

This is a PARSE REST API question. I need to send some json to query the parse server using the Parse REST API. The json needs to contain two keys with the same name "$or". The first key/value is ignored and the second key/value is used by the server. I realise dictionaries can't have two keys with the same name. I've spent a fair bit of time looking at the documentation but its unclear how multiple $or can be done. Is there any way around this?

```
    import json,httplib,urllib
    connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
    params = urllib.urlencode({"where":json.dumps({
           "gender": "male",
           "$or": [
             {
               "brand": "nike"
             },
             {
               "brand": "adidas"
             }
           ],
           "$or": [
             {
               "prim_color": "red"
             },
             {
               "prim_color": "blue"
             }
           ] 
         })})
    connection.connect()
    connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/My_Class?%s' % params, '', {
           "X-Parse-Application-Id": "API-ID",
           "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "REST-KEY"
         })
    result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
    print result
```

Comment: If the first value is ignored, do you really need to send it?

Comment: Yes, both values is necessary. The first key value is querying the brand field in the database. The second key value is querying the colour field. The application logic needs the results from both fields.

Comment: More likely you're misunderstanding their API and don't actually need this.

Comment: A more practically helpful suggestion would be useful.

Comment: Well maybe we could help if you told us what you actually want to say with your query. It's rather hard to tell from something that doesn't work...

Comment: I was hoping someone with knowledge of the Parse REST API would comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [doc](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#query-constraints), `$or` accept an array with one or more conditions to optionally fulfill:

```
import json,httplib,urllib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
params = urllib.urlencode({"where":json.dumps({
       "gender": "male",
       "$or": [
         {
           "brand": "nike"
         },
         {
           "brand": "adidas"
         },
         {
           "prim_color": "red"
         },
         {
           "prim_color": "blue"
         }
       ]
     })})
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/Player?%s' % params, '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "${APPLICATION_ID}",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "${REST_API_KEY}"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

---

***Edit:*** Ok, you want to have at least one brand/color from your lists.
Sadly their parser is pretty bad and you cannot do complex query (In your case even doing an `$and` with `$or` inside...). Where's operators cannot be embedded into others (and only `$or` is implemented so far).

Anyway you can use `$in` to use as an `$or` condition ...

```
import json,httplib,urllib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
params = urllib.urlencode({"where":json.dumps({
       "gender": "male",
       "brand": { "$in": ["nike", "adidas"] }
       "prim_color": { "$in": ["red", "blue"] }
     })})
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/Player?%s' % params, '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "${APPLICATION_ID}",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "${REST_API_KEY}"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

Comment: I'm aware that $or can take an array. I'm using the $or with an array in the code above. The question is how do I query two different fields with $or.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as brands != nike or adidas are shown in the results. What I am looking to do is (brands=nike or adidas and colour= red or blue)

Comment: Yep, I understood quite late your problem. 
Anyway, there is a trick, look at my last edit.

Comment: Its a good workaround. It works, thanks. Do you know if there's a way to add regular expressions with $in ? Previously, I was doing {"brand": {"$regex": "nike","$options":"i"}} with each expression in $or. Can I still do "brand": { "$in": [{"$regex": "nike","$options":"i"}, {"$regex": "adidas","$options":"i"}] } ?

Comment: No, `$in` only take strings. But you can replace the `$in` by a `$regex`: `{"name":{"$regex":"^(nike|addidas)$"}}` and add some complexity if required...

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been very helpful.